# How can I recursively calculate a value

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I have this table.

```
Bundles

id | parent_id | quantity
 1 | 0         | 1
 2 | 1         | 4
 3 | 2         | 5
```

I want to get the total quantity of a bundle with id 3, which is `1 * 4 * 5 = 20` items

Can this be done with a single query?

Comment: It's like you got 5 bundles, each consisting of 4 bundles, each consisting of 1 item. That is `5*4*1 = 20`.

Comment: Use Common Table Expression (CTE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using CTE:

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (id int, parent_id int, quantity int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (id, parent_id, quantity)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 1),
    (2, 1, 4),
    (3, 2, 5),
    (4, 0, 7),
    (5, 4, 10)
;
```

**CTE to return total of `id=3` and it's parent items:**

```
;WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT id, parent_id, quantity
    FROM Table1
    WHERE id = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.id, T.parent_id, T.quantity
    FROM Table1 T
       JOIN myCTE C ON T.id = C.parent_id
)
SELECT EXP(sum(log(quantity))) 
FROM myCTE
```

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcbbb/3)

Multiplication method for values in a column, `SELECT EXP(sum(log(quantity)))`, taken from [**here**](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/Sachin.Nandanwar/sql-server-bi/10/sql-server-multiplying-all-the-values-in-a-column).

Comment: I am trying to create a CTE that will generate one row per record, with the quantity column calculated, but it gives me crazy results. What is wrong with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcbbb/11) ?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask it separately and link back to this one.